# use And with multiple variables in switch-case statements?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a code like this :

```
if(x==1 && y==2){
    something...
    }
    else if(x==4 && y==6){
    something...
    }
    else{
    something...
    }
```

Can I convert it to a switch case statement

Comment: no you can't... why do you want that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with if statements?

Comment: I don't quite agree with the downvotes. Even though it looks like an RTFM question, asking if we can "switch/case" combinations of several variables is not stupid IMO. It would make the code more readable. But I agree it's probably too localized a problem to introduce that in the language

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator I agree, I haven't downvoted the question, I just think people are a little confused why the OP would want this done.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I would imagine its because its not fully clear what the op is trying to achieve and it doesn't show research effort

Answer (score 1):

You can't since switch is taking only one variable; and you have two variables.
You can always refactor your code a little bit though.

Like:

```
if (x==1 && y==2) {
  //something...
  return;
}

if (x==4 && y==6) {
  //something...
  return;
}

//something...
```

Much more readable (imho).

**EDIT**

This is crazy :) but since your variables are integer you can combine them into one long variable and use the switch.

Like:

```
switch ((((long)x) << 32) + y) {
  case ((1L << 32) + 2):
    break;
  case ((4L << 32) + 6):
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: If you are in my team and you want to keep your job, don't even think of doing that ;-)

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator - yes - combining two integers into long so they can fit into switch is kind of code joke; I hope that it'll be received that way :)

Answer (score 1):

Well.... if you have to this would work: WARNING - HACK CODE

```
int x;
int y;
var @switch= new Dictionary<Func<bool> statement, Action doIfTrue>
{
    {() => x == 1 && y == 2, something},
    {() => x == 4 && y == 6, somethingElse}
    {() => true, () = {} } // fallback action
};

@switch.Where(pair => pair.Key()).Select(pair => pair.Value).First()();
```

This could probably be written a bit more terse.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend a bit on how the bigger picture code looks, but I've used the following technique occasionally.

```
switch (x*100+y) {
case 102:
// something...
break;
case 406:
// something...
break;
default:
// something...
}
```

It's pretty readable, but can get out of hand.